# CSV file split values all null

Tags: java

I'm working on this method that gets data from a csv file and stores them into arrays. The code I have compiles but the values for every array are "null". I have no idea why this is happening.

The csv file looks like this but continues for 91 lines:

sunday,9/1/2016,,,,,16:00,20:00
monday,9/2/2016,8:00,12:00,,,,
tuesday,9/3/2016,8:00,12:00,12:00,16:00,,
Wednesday,9/4/2016,,,,,16:00,20:00
thursday,9/5/2016,8:00,12:00,,,,
Friday,9/6/2016,,,12:00,16:00,,
Saturday,9/7/2016,,,,,16:00,20:00

```
public static void getData() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File timeSheets = new File("timeSheets.csv");
    Scanner ts = new Scanner(timeSheets);
    int n = 0, c = 0;

    String temp;

    while (ts.hasNext()) {
        temp = ts.nextLine();
        c++;
    }

    String[] field = new String[8];
    String[] day = new String[c];
    String[] date = new String[c];
    Integer[] morn = new Integer[c];
    Integer[] after = new Integer[c];
    Integer[] night = new Integer[c];

    while (ts.hasNext()) {
        temp = ts.nextLine();
        field = temp.split(",");
        day[n] = field[0];
        date[n] = field[1];

        if (field[4].equals("")) {
            morn[n] = 0;
        } else {
            morn[n] = (int) (Double.parseDouble(field[4].replace(":", "."))
                    - Double.parseDouble(field[3].replace(":", ".")));
        }

        if (field[6].equals("")) {
            after[n] = 0;
        } else {
            after[n] = (int) (Double.parseDouble(field[6].replace(":", "."))
                    - Double.parseDouble(field[5].replace(":", ".")));
        }

        if (field[8].equals("")) {
            night[n] = 0;
        } else {
            night[n] = (int) (Double.parseDouble(field[8].replace(":", "."))
                    - Double.parseDouble(field[7].replace(":", ".")));

        }
        n++;
    }
    System.out.print(day.length);
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < day.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(day[i]);
    }

    ts.close();
}
```

Comment: You exhaust all the lines in the first while loop - so nothing is left when the second loop starts... You could add a `ts = new Scanner(timeSheets);` before the second loop. But then reading a file twice just to get the size of the arrays is quite inefficient...

Answer (score 1):

I just try to run your code. I see that the second while have been never looped. The method ts.hasNext() always return false. Because the stream resource has been read in the first while and it was closed.

Solution: you should initialize object scanner again.

Note: you can verify what i said by printing scanner object. You will get the result such as:

```
java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=238][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=true][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=\.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q?\E][infinity string=\Q?\E]7
```

Answer (score -1):

You're not reading the file. `new File("timeSheets.csv")` only creates a reference to a file. You have to read the contents of that file.

There are plenty of libraries that make doing this easy. The basic class in rt.jar that offers this functionality is [`FileReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html).

Comment: Not really: `Scanner ts = new Scanner(timeSheets);`